# Impala - AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list

Tags: impala

This query that I am doing in impala does not work for me, how else could I do it? In Hive if I was allowed in this style but in Impala it is not allowed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygdTb.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hive currently doesnt support subqueries in select list. Not sure how your sql is working in hive. pls refer to this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Subqueries+in+SELECT    Now, you need to change the subqriest to joins...